# How to write proper private method in JavaScript class with Babel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, babeljs

I was doing GraphQL tutorial from Apollo server. Now I am trying to add batching from this part - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/data-sources/#batching

I know I can use `private` in TypeScript. But not sure how to use in JS.

As far as I've searched, I installed two babel plugins, `class-properties` and `private-methods`.

```
// .babelrc

{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions"
  ]
}
```

Here's the code:

```js
// datasource.js

import DataLoader from 'dataloader';

class PostAPI extends DataSource {
  constructor({ knex }) {
    super();
    this.knex = knex;
  }

  initialize(config) {
    this.context = config.context;
  }

  // ERROR HERE!
  #postLoader = new DataLoader(ids =>
    this.knex('posts')
      .whereIn('id', ids)
      .select()
      .then(rows => ids.map(id => rows.find(x => x.id === id)))
  );

  async findAll() {
    const posts = await this.knex('posts').select();

    if (!posts.length) return [];
    console.log(posts);
    return posts;
  }

  async findOne({ id: idArg } = {}) {
    /*
    const post = await this.knex('posts')
      .where('id', idArg)
      .first();
    */

    const post = await this.postLoader.load(idArg);

    if (!post) return;
    return post;
  }
}
```

And it gives error when I query a single post (findOne):

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot read property 'load' of undefined",
    }
  ]
}
```

Also, eslint warns that `#` is 'Invalid character'.

Here's my `.eslintrc`:

```
// .eslintrc.json

{
  "root": true,
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "allowImportExportEverywhere": false,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "globalReturn": false
    }
  },
  "plugins": ["babel"],
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "prettier"],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "rules": {},
  "globals": {}
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `#` is part of the name of the field. So you need to use `#` everywhere you use it:

```
const post = await this.#postLoader.load(idArg);
// ---------------------^
```

Here's a simple example using a private field (and also a private method):

```
class Example {
    #foo = 42;

    publicMethod() {
        console.log("From publicMethod:", this.#foo);
        this.#privateMethod();
    }

    #privateMethod() {
        console.log("From #privateMethod:", this.#foo);
    }
}

const e = new Example();
console.log(e.publicMethod());
```

[Live on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTaBvAUASAGIAzAexOgF5oAWAJgG4dpp8UBXAIxAEtgBZdABcAFiQAmACgCU2Js2h5gJAHYQSGAHQgSAcwkAiAGIAnEkmjsuvASPEAufQBpoI7hA3EyUxvN8vhbh4oxtwAbmCC6Daikt74AL5y-ATBYRFRQjHSsr6KKmqa2npGpuYpIeGR0fZO_oGeJHF4iYk4SqqC0JhUyugA7nCIqBjSjO0F6Fq6EpOWPPyZ4tLeQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-2%2Ces2015-loose&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.5.5&externalPlugins=%40babel%2Fplugin-proposal-class-properties%407.5.5).

---

> Also, eslint warns that # is 'Invalid character'.

[Private fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) are still only a Stage 3 proposal, not yet standardized. ESLint doesn't seem to have an option for supporting them.

Comment: I feel so stupid for nothing having thought about this before. Thank you very much :)